# Cant create iframe with fixed position

Tags: html, css

I need to create iframe with fixed (absolute) position.
I usesd

```
<iframe src="http://www.whatismyreferer.com" width="300" height="300" style="position: fixed; left: 100; top: 10"></iframe>
```

But it not works :(
My iframe showed like styles "left" and "top" are 0

So question is how to create iframe with fixed position on the page and correctly set the left and top params?

Regards!

Comment: Possible duplicate found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195971/iframe-with-a-css-fixed-position-possible

Comment: units. `10` doesn't mean anything. `10px` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to `100px` and `10px` for the positioning to take effect.

When using CSS or inline CSS you need to specify the pixels (px) otherwise it will have problems taking affect.

Comment: Thanks! Works great at all modern browsers but IE7. I will search the way to solve.

Comment: No problem, If you wouldn't mind voting my answer as correct I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a div around your iframe, and apply your style settings to that div rather than the iframe:

```
<div style="position: fixed; left: 100; top: 10">    
<iframe src="http://www.whatismyreferer.com" width="300" height="300" ></iframe>
</div>
```

since the new div contains the iframe, you should be able to control it that way